# My figure with subfigures included has been numbered twice

Tags: floats, numbering, subfloats

For some reason, my figure has been numbered at the top and the bottom, with two different numbers.

Here is the code that I am using.

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{TiO__15_58_004_01_05_18_.png}
        \caption[Network2]%
        {{\small 15 minutes 58 seconds.}}    
        \label{fig:gg}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\textwidth}  
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{TiO__31_54_004_01_05_18_.png}
        \caption[]%
        {{\small 31 minutes 54 seconds}}    
        \label{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \vskip\baselineskip
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\textwidth}   
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{TiO__35_05_004_01_05_18_.png}
        \caption[]%
        {{\small 35 minutes 5 seconds}}    
        \label{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \quad
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\textwidth}   
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{TiO__40_42_004_01_05_18_.png}
        \caption[]%
        {{\small 40 minutes 42 seconds}}    
        \label{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \vskip\baselineskip
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\textwidth}   
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{TiO__43_51_004_01_05_18_.png}
        \caption[]%
        {{\small 43 minutes 51 seconds}}    
        \label{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption[ A selection of stills ]
    {\small A selection of stills from video footage of TiO\textsubscript{2} in a solution of LiOH. } 
    \label{fig:bubbles}
\end{figure}
```

I am using an IoP set of packages for report submissions, so my preamble is quite complex, but here are my packages.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,final]{iopart}
\newcommand{\gguide}{{\it Preparing graphics for IOP journals}}
%Uncomment next line if AMS fonts required
\usepackage{iopams}  
\usepackage[breaklinks=true,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xfrac}
```

[image: My figure has been numbered at the top and the bottom, with two different numbers.]

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)? After adding a documentclass and removing the `iopams` package {which is not included in texlive} I see no problem with the numbering....

Comment: While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Comment: Your code doesn't give rise to the screenshot you posted. For instance, the screenshot contains what appears to be a cross-referencing call-out that suggests that your real document loads the `hyperref` package. Do you load the `hyperref` package? If so, is it loaded last?

Comment: Are you sure Figure 4 isn't from some other  figure/caption?  BTW, short captions in subfigures are pointless, as they aren't saved to the aux file.  \label{} is also a bad idea.

Comment: @JohnKormylo what exactly do you mean by "short captions", I took the general layout of this subfigure from another answer on tex. Also what is wrong with using label? it seems to work well in this case as I can refer to specific subfigures within the main figure.

Comment: `\caption[short caption]{long caption}`  puts "long caption" in the figure and "short caption" in the `\listoffigures`.  Subfigure caption will not (cannot) appear in the list of figures.  \label{name} is fine, so long as you don't duplicate names.  (It creates a macro  `\r@name`.)

Answer (score 1):

Embarrassingly I just realised that I had an empty figure in the code with no image imported. I didn't realise that Latex adds an empty figure in this case.

Thank you anyway for everyone's help.

Comment: Presumably you had `\caption{}` in that figure? It's the caption that is numbered, the images are irrelevant for the numbering. By the way, by short caption John Kormylo likely referred to your use of `\caption[]{..}`, the square brackets are used to define a separate caption text that will be displayed in the list of figures (if you have one of those).